# ReactJs: Set data- attributes on elements without JSX

Tags: reactjs

React supports data-* and aria-* attributes on elements. When using the component API, I would guess these attributes could be set just like the rest:

```
React.DOM.div({style: {...}, dataMyFoo: 'bar'}, ...)
```

Nope. That doesn't work. The `dataMyFoo` attribute is silently ignored. I read somewhere that these need to be all lowercase. How about:

```
React.DOM.div({style: {...}, datamyfoo: 'bar'}, ...)
```

Again, silently ignored.

Is this possible? If so, what is the secret? I spent quite a while searching without finding the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is to use hyphen-separated all lowercase names for the data attribute, like so:

```
React.DOM.div({style: {...}, 'data-my-foo': 'bar'}, ...)
```

Note that you must quote the attribute name in this case, since hyphens are not allowed in identifiers in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

We're considering moving to a `dataSet: {myFoo: 'bar'}` model in the future, which would put `data-my-foo="bar"` into the DOM. This follows closely the DOM API for accessing data attributes.

Comment: @PaulO'Shannessy that sounds perfect. One of the things I initially tried was `data: {myFoo: 'bar'}` so this closely follows what I was naturally inclined to do.

Comment: What about data-* attributes that have no value? should you just do `{ 'data-foo-bar': true }`? or something else?

Comment: I'm on v0.12.1. {'data-foo-bar': true} renders as <... data-foo-bar="true"> whereas {'data-foo-bar': ''} renders as <... data-foo-bar> so I might go with that.